# Appending a function in a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming

I have integrant function which is the product of several cumulative probability functions and a density function.

For only two events the integrant function is simply the product of a cumulative probability and a density function:

```
function(value) pnorm(value,mean = mean2 ,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
dnorm(value,mean = mean1, sd = sigma)
```

for every new event I need to multiply with another cumulative probability function. Thus, for three alternatives the function turns into:

```
function(value) pnorm(value,mean = mean2 ,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
 pnorm(value,mean = mean1,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
 dnorm(value,mean = mean0, sd = sigma)
```

for four:

```
 function(value) pnorm(value,mean = mean3 ,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
 pnorm(value,mean = mean2,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
 pnorm(value,mean = mean1,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
 dnorm(value,mean = mean0, sd = sigma)
```

and so forth...

I am trying to build a loop that creates this function on the fly for any number of events. I have tried different approaches to generalize the function but nothing has worked so far for me. Any ideas about how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

With the approach I'm proposing, you pass to the function a vector (`meanvec`) whose first element is the `mean` used in the `dnorm` part and the others are used in `pnorm`. I'm assuming that the `sigma` is always the same. With this approach, you can pass any number of elements in the `meanvec` argument.

```
myfun<-function(value,meanvec,sigma) {
    valuelong<-rep(value,each=length(meanvec)-1)
    ppart<-apply(matrix(pnorm(valuelong,meanvec[-1],sigma),nrow=length(meanvec)-1),2,prod)
    if (length(meanvec)>1) ppart*dnorm(value,meanvec[1],sigma) else dnorm(value,meanvec[1],sigma)
}
```

Example:

```
mean0<-1
mean1<-2
mean2<-3
mean3<-4
value<-runif(100)
sigma<-2
#here define your not generalized function with 3 pnorm
oldfun<-function(value) pnorm(value,mean = mean3 ,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
pnorm(value,mean = mean2,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
pnorm(value,mean = mean1,sd = sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)*
dnorm(value,mean = mean0, sd = sigma)
all.equal(oldfun(value),myfun(value,c(mean0,mean1,mean2,mean3),sigma))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: It looks like there's some trouble with vectorising the inputs, as  `myfun(2:10,1,1)` is failing. I think you could try the same approach I've used for handling inputs (i.e. let `pnorm` handle vectorising the inputs itself)

Comment: Tx for noticing. I let `pnorm` handle the vectorization. I made un update to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it that I think is pretty easy to follow.

The key to this is the `Reduce` function. i.e. `Reduce('+',1:3)` is the same as `1+2+3`, and `Reduce('*',1:3)` is the same as `1*2*3`.

```
do_it <- function(value, means, sigma) {

  # get the pnorm values (and then ignore the first result)
  pn_result <- pnorm(value, means, sigma, lower.tail = TRUE)[-1]

  # now get the dnorm (i.e. the first mean)
  dn_result  <- dnorm(value[1], means[1], sd = sigma[1])

  # Use reduce function to multiply all values together
  Reduce("*", c(pn_result, dn_result))

}
```

And now use the function like so:

```
> do_it(value = 7,   means = 2:4, sigma = 2)
[1] 0.007992577
> do_it(value = 7,   means = 2:4, sigma = 1:3)
[1] 1.222387e-06
> do_it(value = 7:9, means = 2:4, sigma = 1:3)
[1] 1.406878e-06
```

As per Nicola's comment, yes, this is slower.

```
microbenchmark(
  do_it(7, 2:1000, 2),
  myfun(7, 2:1000, 2),
  time = 10000,
  unit = 'eps'
)
```

About 4-5 times slower i.e. ~5ms vs ~1ms to run with 1000 means.

```
Unit: evaluations per second
                expr         min           lq        mean       median           uq          max neval
 do_it(7, 2:1000, 2)    1006.555     2234.863     2299.33     2373.921     2409.485 2.554957e+03   100
 myfun(7, 2:1000, 2)    5627.335     9837.340    10040.78    10169.636    10497.424 1.155161e+04   100
                time 9523809.524 30776515.152 48510649.75 38461538.462 57189542.484 1.666667e+08   100
```

Edit: Have updated to vectorise the code, added a benchmark

Comment: Warning: this solution is not vectorized, in the sense that accepts just a length one vector for the `value` argument. If you want to use it with `integrate` (as maybe implied in the OP) you have to vectorize it. I suspect also that it is much slower than my solution.

Comment: It wasn't sure if the OP was interested in vectorising `value` and `sigma`, but I've updated in case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think we agree on the meaning of vectorization. The idea is to give a vector of length `n` as `value` argument and to give back a lenght `n` result. Your function returns always just one value. You should also check that your function gives the same result as the "manual" ones provided in the OP. Also, your handling of the vectorization is plain wrong (the point is that each value of `means` get calculated for each value in `values`; your function does other things). The old one was just unvectorized; this one is plain wrong I guess.